# Approval workflow return same Approval status as Approved even list item rejected by approver

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I create an approval workflow as below

which always return Approved outcome even if its rejected, Please suggest the correct way to return value Rejected if Approvar rejected the list item

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the value of the workflow variable temp? It will be better to check it as it seems to get value in the approval process.

For troubleshooting you issue, I will suggest to add some log actions to output the value of variables like the approval status and the temp in before and after the approval and if condition. It will help us to see where the workflow starts to get a wrong value.